# Set Excel sheet background image

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I would like to ask you if there is any way setting image as sheet background using Apache Excel POI? I was only able to find how to set background color of the cell. I want same functionality you get using **Excel -> Page Layout -> Background**.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the type of the `Excel` file.

For `Office Open XML` format `*.xlsx` it is as simple as:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;

public class CreateExcelXSSFSheetBackgroundPicture {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelXSSFSheetBackgroundPicture.xlsx")) {

   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

   //add picture data to this workbook.
   FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("dummy.png");
   byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
   int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
   is.close();

   //add relation from sheet to the picture data
   String rID = sheet.addRelation(null, XSSFRelation.IMAGES, workbook.getAllPictures().get(pictureIdx))
                      .getRelationship().getId();
   //set background picture to sheet
   sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewPicture().setId(rID);

   workbook.write(out);

  }

 }
}
```

This code needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` for `apache poi 4.1.1` (lower versions for older releases) as mentioned in [FAQ N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

For binary `BIFF` format `*.xls` it is as complicated as [Using java.awt.image.BufferedImage for creating BIFF8 BITMAP record takes much time - Is there any better approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419600/using-java-awt-image-bufferedimage-for-creating-biff8-bitmap-record-takes-much-t).

Comment: addNewPicture() return CTSheetBackgroundPicture,but CTSheetBackgroundPicture  class not found

Comment: @Jinceon: This code needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` for `apache poi 4.1.1` (lower versions for older releases) as mentioned in [FAQ N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

Answer (score 0):

If you use poi 5. the maven repo should.
it is only for xlsx.

`<poi.version>5.0.0</poi.version>`

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-full</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

spring boot and use lombok

```java
    public void addWatermark() throws IOException {
        val workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(this.inputStream);
        XSSFWorkbook wb =(XSSFWorkbook) workbook;
        // get an image input stream from classpath
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("bub.png");
        InputStream inputStream = classPathResource.getInputStream();
        int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream), Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
        inputStream.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
            String rID = sheet.addRelation(null, XSSFRelation.IMAGES,wb
                    .getAllPictures().get(pictureIdx)).getRelationship().getId();
            sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewPicture().setId(rID);
        }
    }
```